# PHP redirect users if not logged in

Tags: php

I am searching for a way to redirect all users that are not logged in from any file in a specific directory.

I have a directory called `admin`.

The only user with a login will be myself.

I use a script such as this to check if I am logged in and if not then redirect.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user']) {
 if($_SESSION['user'] == "username") {
   echo "Welcome, " . $_SESSION['user'];
}
else {
 header("Location: index.php");
}
}
```

Pretty simple. Pretty straight forward. No need for extra security since I am not handling any sensitive data and my admin pages cannot interfere with how my site runs.

But how could I create a redirect to check for that specific `admin` directory?

This script is in my `functions.php` file which is included on every single page so I need a way to exclude every file except that directory or if it's possible to use an array and just list the pages that should not be viewable unless logged in.

With some tweaking I was thinking something like this would work.

Problem is what if I have two `index.php` files? One for main directory and one for my subdirectories?

I included `$directory = "admin/";` in the script, but I'm not sure how to work that into it to only redirect if those files are in that directory.

Notice: I wrote these examples in a hurry so they may have other errors. Sorry if they do.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user']) {
 if($_SESSION['user'] == "username") {
   echo "Welcome, " . $_SESSION['user'];
}
else {
 $directory = "admin/";
 $redirect[] = array();
 $redirect[] = "page1.php";
 $redirect[] = "page2.php";
 if (in_array(($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], $redirect)) {
  header("Location: index.php");
}
}
}
```

How can I add the directory to the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, you want anybody without a `$_SESSION['user']` accessing a file within the `/admin/` directory to be redirected?

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['user']) && stristr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'],'admin'){
   header('Location: http://www.goodbye.com');
}
```

Notice the full URL, including http in the header.  an HTTP header must have a full, absolute URL to function properly.

Comment: But isn't that looking for a script named admin like admin.php?

Comment: iirc, it should include the path from the  root, you can try this by echoing the value of it. or do a `print_r($_SERVER);`

Comment: Ok now that I've read it I think I understand this a little. I'm trying to keep using an array because I may have one or two files in the `admin` directory in the future that can be accessible to the public so I don't want to redirect every single file.

Comment: That would be a strange thing to do, allowing public to access an admin folder? in what situation would that be a good thing?

Comment: Depends on the file I place. It's a `just in case` thing.